# creating a database for houses (SQLite3)

Tags: database, database-design, sqlite

got a python sqlite3 spider crawling through a website and essentially got an address, and the dates that it was sold for along with the corresponding prices it was sold for. The first database is for address, postcode, number of bedrooms and second is points in time it was sold I am thinking of arranging the second database that has prices like so :
 `(Unique_id, date_1, sale_price_1, date_2, sale_price_2...etc..etc)`

but this does not seem very efficient, for example, I may put down five date and sale columns but the crawler may come across a house sold seven times... is there a more efficient way to organise the second database of sold prices?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

I would create two tables: one for `houses`, and one for `transactions` and link them via a foreign key.

Each `house` will only have one row in the `houses` table, but may have any number of rows in the `transactions` table.

The `transactions` table will have a foreign key to the `house` that was sold, along with columns about the sale, such as date and sale price.